# ¿Cómo limitar la cantidad de letras que obtengo de una cadena y convertir en mayusculas el resultado?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código, lo que hace es obtener la primera letra de cada palabra ingresada en un input (sea mayúscula o minúscula), para luego almacenarla en otra variable.

```
var palabras = "Nombre de algo Que quiero Obtener"
var respuesta = palabras.replace(/[A-Za-z]+/g, function(match){ 
                   return (match.trim()[0]);
                }); 
var resultado = respuesta.replace(/\s/g, '')

console.log(resultado) // lo que obtengo   =   "NdaQqO"
```

ahora como menciono en el titulo se necesita que la cantidad de letras obtenidas sea `n`, para este caso como ejemplo puse `3`y convertir el resultado en mayúscula.

```
//resultado esperado
console.log(resultado)= "NDA"
```

Comment: Puedes utilizar [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) para reducir el tamaño de la string y [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) para hacerl mayúscula.

Comment: @FranAcuna muchas gracias, me imagine que era algo sencillo, es que soy nuevo en javascript y aun existen metodos que no se como buscarles. si quieres agregalo como respuesta para ponerla como resuelta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) para reducir el tamaño de la string y [`toUpperCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase) para hacerlo mayúscula.